# Generic Method not adding arbitrary Number types in java

Tags: java, generics, generic-collections

I am trying to create a generic method that adds any list of numeric types in java. I would like to be able to use this method to add Integers, Doubles, Longs etc.. 
The below does not seem to work. I get compilation exceptions in eclipse saying: 
`The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) Number, T`
What could be the problemo? Thank you in advance.

```
public static <T extends Number> T sum(ArrayList<T> nums){
    Number retVal = 0.0;
    for (T val : nums){
        retVal = retVal+ val;
    }
    return (T) retVal;
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the error?

Comment: why? Why is it doing that? Its a number, and I should be able to add it. period.

Comment: What if I created a an `ImaginaryNumber extends Number`, what would be the result of the `+` operator?

Comment: Java cannot add number to unknown class, you defined `ArrayList<T>` define it as `ArrayList<T extends Number>`

Comment: Sotirios, great point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider what the Java Language Specification says about the additive `+` operator

> If the type of either operand of a + operator is String, then the
>   operation is string concatenation.
>
> **Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the + operator must be
>   a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type, or a
>   compile-time error occurs.**

`Number` is not a type that is convertible to a primitive. You therefore cannot use the `+` operator with variables of that type.

Consider using a different type or overloading your methods for each numeric type.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to overload my method. What's an alternative?

Comment: The only two possibilities are doing what Prabhakaran proposes (but then you have to decide on a type) in their answer and using overloaded methods.

Comment: I was thinking of using instanceof to do a type check before adding and then returning the appropriate Number subtype

Comment: @ImtiazAhmad I guess that is _fine_, but do you really have a situation where you declare a `List<Number>` and put all sorts of types?

Comment: @Imtiaz Ahmad: You can’t do that as callers could pass any subclasses of `Number` to your method including classes unknown to you. Further, the passed list can be parametrized with the abstract `Number` class directly instead of a concrete subclass. Such a list can contain an arbitrary mixture of `Number` types, so there is no “appropriate `Number` subtype” in this case. `List<Number> l=Arrays.<Number>asList(new BigDecimal(4), 42.0, (byte)1, new AtomicInteger(300)); Number n=YourClass.sort(l);`

Answer (score 0):

instead of   `retVal = retVal+ val;`

Use like below.

```
retVal = retVal.doubleValue()+ val.doubleValue();
```

Comment: But that's just making an assumption that the numerical value will be a double. My numerical value could be anything. Double, Integer, Long etc..

Answer (score 0):

Consider what you are asking for.  You want a collection into which you can place numbers of arbitrary types, and perform operations like `sum()`.  There are eight distinct number subtypes (BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short, not counting the atomic versions).

You will have noticed that `java.lang.Number` has no arithmetic methods, like `add()` or `multiply()`. You can't just go adding up instances of `Number` subclasses willy-nilly; you must consider each possible pairing, decide the rules for converting one or both to a common type for which addition is defined, and then decide what the result type is.

Then this has to be applied for each number you add to the running total.  This is a non-trivial design task.

Luckily you can piggy-back off the design decisions already present for primitive types in the JLS, but it's still going to be a lot of work.